# CumSum that counts values only once based on group

Tags: r, data.table, data-manipulation, cumulative-sum

I am currently trying to create a cumulative sum column that will create a cumulative sum based on Game_ID, but only counts a value correlated with Game_ID a single time. For instance, Player A takes 20 shots in Game_ID == 1 and 13 shots in Game_ID == 2. For the cumulative sum, I want the Shot_Count value (based on Game_ID) to only be counted a single time, despite appearing in the Shot_Count column multiple times. Consider the following data set:

```
Name         Game_ID       Shot_Count        CumSum_Shots
Player A         1             20                20 
Player B         1             15                15 
Player A         1             20                20
Player A         2             13                33 ## (20 + 13)
Player A         2             13                33 ## (20 + 13)
Player B         2             35                50 ## (15 + 35)
Player A         3             30                63 ## (33 + 30)
Player B         3             20                70 ## (50 + 20)
Player A         3             30                63 ## (33 + 30)
Player A         4             12                75 ## (63 + 12)
Player A         4             12                75 ## (63 + 12)
Player B         4             10                80 ## (70 + 10)
```

Keep in mind there are other variables that make it such that Rows 1 and 3, etc. are not duplicates. I just wanted to simplify the data set to the variables that were relevant.

I tried to used cumsum function with the data.table library:

```
library(data.table)
dt[ , CumSum_Shots := cumsum(Shot_Count), by = list(dt$Name, dt$Game_ID)]
```

However, this sums the Shot_Count row based on game (i.e. CumSum_Shots row three would be 40). It makes sense that this code does this, but I am not sure what data.table syntax exists in order to make the code consider unique values of dt$Game_ID.

Comment: If any of the solution solved your problem then you should [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235)

Answer (score 5):

Unique, compute, then merge back:

```
dt[unique(dt, by = c('Name', 'Game_ID', 'Shot_Count'))
       [, Cum_Shots := cumsum(Shot_Count), by = Name]
   , on = .(Name, Game_ID), Cum_Shots := Cum_Shots]
```

R is a dirty language.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you're using `data.table` already, then you can do this:

Code:

```
library(data.table)
merge(dt, 
      dt[, Shot_Count[1], .(Name, Game_ID)][, .(CumSum_Shots = cumsum(V1), Game_ID), Name], 
      sort = FALSE)
```

Output:

> ```
>         Name Game_ID Shot_Count CumSum_Shots
>  1: Player A       1         20           20
>  2: Player B       1         15           15
>  3: Player A       1         20           20
>  4: Player A       2         13           33
>  5: Player A       2         13           33
>  6: Player B       2         35           50
>  7: Player A       3         30           63
>  8: Player B       3         20           70
>  9: Player A       3         30           63
> 10: Player A       4         12           75
> 11: Player A       4         12           75
> 12: Player B       4         10           80
> ```

Explanation:

- `dt[, Shot_Count[1], .(Name, Game_ID)]`: Take first shot (`[1]`) by `Group_ID` and `Name`. Does what OP wanted (*only be counted a single time*).
- `[, .(CumSum_Shots = cumsum(V1), Game_ID), Name]`: calculate sum per `Name` and keep `Group_ID` info.
- `merge(dt, ..., sort = FALSE)`: merge with original data and leave original ordering.

Input (`dt`):

```
structure(list(Name = c("Player A", "Player B", "Player A", "Player A", 
"Player A", "Player B", "Player A", "Player B", "Player A", "Player A", 
"Player A", "Player B"), Game_ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), Shot_Count = c(20L, 15L, 20L, 13L, 13L, 
35L, 30L, 20L, 30L, 12L, 12L, 10L)), .Names = c("Name", "Game_ID", 
"Shot_Count"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

Edit:

When working with long strings of `data.table` syntax I prefer `magrittr` pipes:

```
library(magrittr)
dt %>%
    .[, Shot_Count[1], .(Name, Game_ID)] %>%
    .[, .(CumSum_Shots = cumsum(V1), Game_ID), Name] %>%
    merge(dt, ., sort = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Without a merge you could `cumsum` the unique values (by `Name`, `Game` and `Shots`), then `rep` it to get the correct length.

```
dt[, CumSum_Shots2 := rep(cumsum(Shot_Count[!duplicated(Game_ID)]), times = .SD[,.N,by = .(Game_ID, Shot_Count)]$N) , 
   by = .(Name)]

dt
 #      Name Game_ID Shot_Count CumSum_Shots CumSum_Shots2
 #1: PlayerA       1         20           20            20
 #2: PlayerB       1         15           15            15
 #3: PlayerA       1         20           20            20
 #4: PlayerA       2         13           33            33
 #5: PlayerA       2         13           33            33
 #6: PlayerB       2         35           50            50
 #7: PlayerA       3         30           63            63
 #8: PlayerB       3         20           70            70
 #9: PlayerA       3         30           63            63
#10: PlayerA       4         12           75            75
#11: PlayerA       4         12           75            75
#12: PlayerB       4         10           80            80
```